# Which Auslander algebras satisfy $Ext_B^1(D(B),B)=0$?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $B$ be the Auslander algebra of a representation-finite algebra $A$.

> Question: When do we have $Ext_B^1(D(B),B)=0$? Can this be expressed in terms of nice properties of $A$?

This is for example true when $A$ is a hereditary Nakayama algebra, but other than for hereditary $A$ I do not know any example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is answered by Theorem 1.20 in the following article:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.4897.pdf